# Js Remove Class not Working

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have a `button` that I used js to add class when clicked which works fine.

It should remove the class on any AJAX response.
I called a `removeclass()` but it **does not remove** the spinning.

I've checked the codes and gone through several other solutions in this forum but I have not been successful.
I will appreciate any help, advice and suggestions given.

```
$(".btn-take").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var that = $(this);

    that.addClass("disabled");
    that.html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');

    // Activate purchase
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "premium/activate_feature",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name : name},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.result == 999) {
                alert("You are not logged in anymore");
                window.location = base_url;
            } else if(data.result == 998) {
                alert("Error, this premium feature doesn't exist.");
                that.removeClass("disabled");
            } else if(data.result == 997) {
                $(".alert-purchase").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-danger").html(not_enough_credits_str).fadeIn();
                that.removeClass("disabled").html("<i class='fa fa-diamond'></i> " + take_it_str);
                scrollTopToStatus();
            } else {
                if(name == "see_who_loves_you") {
                    $(".alert-purchase").html("see_loves_success_str");
                } else if(name == "browse_invisibly") {
                    $(".alert-purchase").html(invisible_success_str).fadeIn();
                } else if(name == "featured_one_week") {
                    $(".alert-purchase").html(featured_one_week_success_str).fadeIn();
                } else if(name == "featured_one_month") {
                    $(".alert-purchase").html(featured_one_month_success_str).fadeIn();
                }

                scrollTopToStatus();

                that.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success").html("Success!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div class="pf_take_it col-md-2">
    <?php if($loves_purchased): ?>
       <a class="btn btn-success disabled">
           <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo $this->lang->line("purchased_btn"); ?>
       </a>
    <?php else: ?>
       <a class="btn btn-danger btn-take" data-name="see_who_loves_you">
           <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> <?php echo $this->lang->line("take_it_btn"); ?>
      </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: it doesnt remove spinner because you have added it as html instead, remove class won't effect the html insead it

Comment: @AnandSiddharth it doesnt remove the class Disabled too

Comment: that.removeClass("disabled") code might not reachable , its written inside `data.result == 997` you may want to write above                 scrollTopToStatus();

Comment: You only remove the disabled in 2 of your ifs - why not move it to after or before the ifs rather than repeating it four times

Answer (score 0):

Try this

that.classList.remove('disabled');